# Hashmap inside a list to process my text file

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a text file to be read and processed (separated by one tab space) which is something like:

```
GroupNum  Id   Name  Address
    1      1   john   USA
    1      2   mike   Uk
    2      3   smith  UK
```

How do i store each row in a map (userId being the key and the remaining being the values)and group in into a list and again map it as groupId with the key and the remaining as values?
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Is that Java? And what exactly is a "ResultSet **file**"?

Comment: Yeah..Its java.. "ResultSet file" is..the displayed resultset is stored a file and read using bufferedreader.

Comment: So it's "just" a file? Has nothing to do (any more) with a `ResultSet`

Comment: I did not get one thing... for a single row can there be more than one groupnum.. that you are trying to create a list.. ?

Comment: Yeah..for single grp num, we can have multiple rows.but ID is unique.

Comment: Yeah..Its a file to be read and processed

Answer (score 1):

create Some Custom Object like `GroupNum` with properties (`GroupNum, Id, Name, Address`).

While reading ResultSet prepare

```
HashMap<String, GroupNum> hm;
while (rs.next) {

GroupNum  gn = new GroupNum ();
// set all values to GroupNum 

hm.put(gn.getGropuNum(), gn);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with help of meta data,

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
int count = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(resultSet.next()){
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
        map.put(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), resultSet.getString(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)));
    }
    list.add(map);
}
```

A generic solution should work for any number of columns.